# Post CSRF check, devise still runs full function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf

In Rails, using devise, if a CSRF Check fails then the user's current session is cleared, i.e., logs the user out, because the server assumes it's an attack (which is the correct/desired behavior). 
But the request, is completed, hence the user record is still created. Hacker can then log in correctly. 
How can I stop the method from continuing once devise realises auth_token is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise doesn't do any checking of the auth token - it's action controller which does this (although it does call `handle_unverified_request` on your controller so that you can customise behaviour). In rails 4 and higher you can also specify what happens by default when the auth token is invalid:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

causes an exception to be raised, which would stop the request being processed.

However I am not sure what this buys you though - CSRF is so that an attacker cannot abuse the fact that the user is already logged into your application, but if the attacker has a valid set of credentials then they don't need to do CSRF in the first place.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. I just wanted an exception to happen whenever a user did something weird